# ASP.NET GridView RowIndex As CommandArgument

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can you access and display the row index of a gridview item as the command argument in a  buttonfield column button?

```
<gridview>
<Columns>
   <asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" 
        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="True" 
        CommandArgument=" ? ? ? " />
.....
```

Comment: Try this Link [get-gridview-rowindex-upon-button-click](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/09/22/get-gridview-rowindex-upon-button-click.aspx)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Here is a very simple way:

```html
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="True" 
                 CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

Comment: For GridView, its DataItemIndex AND NOT ItemIndex. ItemIndex is for the Repeater

Comment: I got the error "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField does not have a DataBinding event." when I tried. But the CommandArgument are set automatically to rowindex (see the answer from Rich).

Comment: but it shows error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Philip.Modules.ItemMapping.ViewItemMapping.gvItem_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

Comment: When the gridview allows paging, this solution does not work. See Mohamed Ahmed Abdel-Hafez's answer, Container.DisplayIndex works exactly as a ButtonField.CommandArgument value.

Answer (score 35):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) says that:

> The ButtonField class automatically populates the CommandArgument property with the appropriate index value. For other command buttons, you must manually set the CommandArgument property of the command button. For example, you can set the CommandArgument to <%# Container.DataItemIndex %> when the GridView control has no paging enabled.

So you shouldn't need to set it manually. A row command with GridViewCommandEventArgs would then make it accessible; e.g.

```
protected void Whatever_RowCommand( object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e )
{
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32( e.CommandArgument );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yep. That's 5 hours of my life I just lost because I didn't read this post first.

Answer (score 13):

Here is Microsoft Suggestion for this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx#Y800

On the gridview add a command button and convert it into a template, then give it a commandname in this case "**AddToCart**" and also add CommandArgument ***"<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"***

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
      CommandName="AddToCart" 
      CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
      Text="Add to Cart" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then for create on the RowCommand event of the gridview identify when the "AddToCart" command is triggered, and do whatever you want from there

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
  {
    // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
    // CommandArgument property.
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
    // from the Rows collection.
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

    // Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.
  }
}
```

**One mistake I was making is that I wanted to add the actions on my template button instead of doing it directly on the RowCommand Event.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will work.

```
<gridview>
<Columns>

            <asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="True" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
        </Columns>
</gridview>
```

Comment: it's with Single Quote:

    CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'

Comment: @balexandre, it is not necessary to have single quote when there is no double quote inside ASP.NET tags

Answer (score 1):

```
void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)e.CommandSource;
    b.CommandArgument = ((GridViewRow)sender).RowIndex.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically bind this data using the RowDatabound event with the GridView:

```
protected void FormatGridView(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
   {
      ((Button)e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("btnSpecial")).CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkAdd" Text="Add" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EmpID"))%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the traditional way and latest version of asp.net framework having strongly typed data and you don't need to use as string like "EMPID"

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtn" runat="server" Text="Text" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("??") %>' OnClick="LnkBtn_Click" />
```

inside your event handler :

```
Protected Sub LnkBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  dim rowIndex as integer = sender.Attributes("RowIndex")
  'Here you can use also the command argument for any other value.
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why the down vote, Container.DataItemIndex does not work when the gridview allows paging. This solution worked just fine (exactly as the ButtonField.CommandArgument value). +1

Answer (score 0):

with paging you need to do some calculation

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) % GridView1.PageSize;
```