# How to access to Data key Row in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview and set a DataKeyNames to ID (`DataKeyNames="ID"`).
In this GridView I crate a column to select a row by Select command.
I want to get row id by datakeyname but I can't do it.

Think my Gridview rows are

```
1
3
4
6
9
10
15
```

Numbers are taken from the database and the gridview are used.
Please help me.
If need more details say.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to assign `rowindex` in `rowdatabound` event to your command then then pass that in command argument found a very nice article about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389403/asp-net-gridview-rowindex-as-commandargument)

Comment: Thank you.I Fix this problem.

Comment: If your problem is fixed then its good. Please accept the answer so that other people know that your problem is solved by this answer and they get benefited