# ASP GridView get row values on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What I'm doing - reset user password on imagebutton click.

Done so far - added GridViewCommandEventHandler - it's firing correctly. Using code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventhandler.aspx). I'm getting an empty string ("") for my e.CommandArgument, and it's throwing an error when running (can't parse "" to int).

I can see in the debugger there is a 'rowIndex' property being stored (correctly for my click) elsewhere in e, can I access this? I would think MSDN's code would work - is there something else I've done to make this error occur or another way to fix it? Thanks.

```
void resetpassword(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // If multiple ButtonField columns are used, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if (e.CommandName == "resetpass")
    {
        // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
        // property to an Integer.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked
        // by the user from the Rows collection. Use the
        // CommandSource property to access the GridView control.
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

        String usrname = row.FindControl("username").ToString();
```

aspx page code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reset Password">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnReset" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                        CommandName="resetpass" ImageUrl="~/Images/glyphicons_044_keys.png" Text="Button" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="70px" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Event add code:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(this.resetpassword);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either pass the `CommandArgument`(assuming you want to pass the primary key field called `PK`):

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>                
      <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtnReset"
        Text="reset password"
        CommandName="resetpass"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Pk") %>'
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

or get the reference of the `GridViewRow` via the `NamingContainer` of your `ImageButton`:

```
WebControl wc = e.CommandSource as WebControl;
GridViewRow row = wc.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
String usrname = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("username")).Text;
```

You can also pass the RowIndex as CommandArgument:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

The `ButtonField` class automatically populates the `CommandArgument` property with the appropriate index value. For other command buttons, you must manually set the `CommandArgument` property of the command button.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the ButtonField/ImageButton - now I know why that part wasn't working! Went with the first option, and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing `CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'`

for your code.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnReset" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
        CommandName="resetpass" ImageUrl="~/Images/glyphicons_044_keys.png" 
Text="Button" />
```

Here is a question on SO [ASP.NET GridView RowIndex As CommandArgument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389403/asp-net-gridview-rowindex-as-commandargument) for further reading.

> The ButtonField class automatically populates the CommandArgument
>   property with the appropriate index value.

[Here is the MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.aspx)

Comment: @Volvox: For further reading on `ButtonField` I have provided MSDN link in my update.