# Can't get gridview row once templatefield button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, gridview

When a `Button` in the `GridView` is clicked I can't seem to get the row index or the row that is to be eliminated, I need the Id and the Complete route of the archive, both of them are on the bound fields of the `GridView`, here is the code I have:

**Gridview Code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvData"
              AllowSorting="False" 
              AllowPaging="True" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" 
              runat="server" 
              EmptyDataText="No existen archivos cargados." 
              Width="100%">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternatingrowstyle" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id"
                   DataField="Id"
                   Visible="false" >
       <HeaderStyle CssClass="left" />
       <ItemStyle CssClass="left" />
       </asp:BoundField>
       <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RutaCompleta"
                   DataField="RutaCompleta"
                   Visible="false" >
       <HeaderStyle CssClass="left" />
       <ItemStyle CssClass="left" />
       </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Archivo">
            <ItemTemplate>          
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
                               CssClass="left"  
                               Target="_blank" 
                               NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("RutaCompleta")%>'  
                               Text='<%#Eval("Archivo")%>'> 
                </asp:HyperLink>             
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="left" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/page_delete.ico"
                           HeaderText="Eliminar">
           <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgDelete"
                            runat="server" 
                            CommandArgument="Delete"
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/page_delete.ico" 
                            OnClick="btnEliminar_Click"
                            OnClientClick="return confirm('¿Esta seguro de eliminar este archivo?');" 
                            ToolTip="Borrar Documento"/>                                                      
           </ItemTemplate>
           <HeaderStyle CssClass="center" />
           <ItemStyle CssClass="center"/>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pagerstyle" />
    <PagerTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Mostrar filas:" />
        <asp:DropDownList   ID="ddlPageSize" 
                            runat="server" 
                            AutoPostBack="true" 
                            CssClass="CombosBox"
                            >
            <asp:ListItem Value="10" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="15" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="20" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDesde" runat="server" Text="Página" />
        <asp:TextBox    ID="txtGoToPage" 
                        runat="server" 
                        AutoPostBack="true" 
                        CssClass="gotopage"
                        />
        <asp:Label ID="lblHasta" runat="server" Text="de " />
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalNumberOfPages" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAnt" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument="Prev" 
                    CommandName="Page" 
                    CssClass="previous" 
                    ToolTip="ant. página" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnProx" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument="Next" 
                    CommandName="Page" 
                    CssClass="next" 
                    ToolTip="prox. página" />
    </PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Int64 intId = 0;
        String strRutaCompleta = String.Empty;

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
        Label lblId = (Label)row.FindControl("lblId");
        Label lblRutaCompleta = (Label)row.FindControl("lblRutaCompleta");

        intId = Convert.ToInt64(lblId.Text.ToString());
        strRutaCompleta = lblRutaCompleta.Text.ToString();

        /*Other part of the code*/
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        /*Other part of the code*/
    }
}
```

I have tried various methods found here on StackOverflow, hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

Comment: why are you not referencing the name of the `GridView` you are working on ? `gdvData`

Comment: In every solution I have found they never reference the Gridview at any moment, could you show me an example???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.Parent.Parent`, I recommend using the `CommandArgument` property of the `ImageButton` and set the dataitem's `Id`.

Here is another post on StackOverflow that give a good bit of code: [ASP.NET GridView RowIndex As CommandArgument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389403/asp-net-gridview-rowindex-as-commandargument)

It appears to me that all you need is the `Id` of the data you want to delete.  So instead of trying to use the row's index, just put the `Id` in the button's `CommandArgument`

**Example:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImgDelete"
                  runat="server" 
                  CommandArgument="Delete"
                  ImageUrl="~/Images/page_delete.ico" 
                  OnClick="btnEliminar_Click"
                  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>'
                  OnClientClick="return confirm('¿Esta seguro de eliminar este archivo?');" 
                  ToolTip="Borrar Documento"/>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Int64 intId = 0;
        ImageButton btn = (sender as ImageButton)
        if(btn != null)
        {
            Int64 tempId;
            if(Int64.TryParse(btn.CommandArgument, out tempId))
            {
                intId = intId;

                /*Other part of the code*/
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        /*Other part of the code*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the data comes from a DataSet that is then bound to the gridview, how should I change the data?

Comment: try: `<yourDataSet>.Container.Components.Item[rowIndex]`

Comment: Alternatively, you can grab the GridViewRow using the index as well: `gdvData.Rows[rowIndex]`

Comment: ok I have gotten the row using the next sentence: GridViewRow row = gdvData.Rows[index]; but how can i acces the column or cell??

Comment: @AndresScarpone, to be honest, I'm not exactly sure how your `DataSet` is structured.  Normally I would have bound a `DataTable` or better yet, an `IEnumberable` of objects, to the `GridView`.  You can try `gridViewRow.DataItem` ... but really you should be interacting with the `DataSet` directly.

Comment: well the dataset contains everithyng from a SQL statement and bring only the data that is bound in the Gridview, the id, The complete route and the archive.

Comment: Then try: `DataRow dr = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowIndex];` ... beyond that you're going to need to set a breakpoint, examine the dataset in memory using *Watch Expressions* and determine how to access your data.

Comment: but the delete method doesn't have the dataset, the only moment the dataset is populated is when the page is loaded.

Comment: Then store the `DataSet` in a variable in the page.  The `Page_Load` will always occur before the button's `Click` event.

Comment: is there any other way to just get the data contained in the gridview??? I mean all the data should already be on it?

Comment: So I tried to use this GridViewRow row = gdvData.Rows[index];
                        intId = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[0]);
but at the moment of converting the row.cells[0] it gave me the following error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Comment: @AndresScarpone: I've updated my answer to store the `Id` in the `CommandArgument`.  To be honest, there is a way to get "the data contained in the gridview" in the button's click event, but that question is worthy of a new question post.  Good luck!

Comment: Yeah but with this method I can't get the route where the Archive is to delete it, but thanks for the method, ill try it later.