# RegisterClientScriptBlock - confirm box return a boolean to aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to do a confirmation box before execute a command. I need to get the response from javascript message box to .cs (asp.net/c#) code..

Here is my code

```
 bool ReturnValue() {
    return false;
 }

  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
     string commandname = e.CommandName;

     if (commandname.Equals("atender")) {
        ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
        if (!ReturnValue()) {
            string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('Are you sure?')){ I need a code here to return a false boolean to my c#}</script>";
            CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
        }
 // There is the code which I want to not execute if the confirmation is false
}




 EDIT:
```

My gridview code:

```
 <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CellSpacing="1" Width="100%" 
            GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" PageSize="5" HorizontalAlign=Left
            >
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="tabela_texto2" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="tabela_texto1" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField ControlStyle-CssClass="botonTransaccional" Text="Status" CommandName="atender" ButtonType="Button" />
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Ver no mapa" CommandName="ver" ButtonType="Button" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried `RegisterStartUpScript`?

Comment: Wrong way. Please show `GridView` code.

Comment: There is issue with original design you are having. Do you want to get client inputs while processing started on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you have to do. First, change you `ButtonField` to a `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Status" CommandName="atender" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your code behind you don't need any kind of logic for this. The `GridView1_RowCommand` event will fire just if you click OK in the confirm window.

Comment: Thanks! It works: call the command method only if the user confirm. But I have a problem...now this line crash the app: string id = `GridView1.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[2].Text; `

Comment: @CodeHunter accept the answer then. For this, what's the error?

Comment: **Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Before these changes, it works**

Comment: @CodeHunter you have to assign a value to it in the aspx.

Comment: Before these changes it works...these e.comandArgument must to returns the row's position. How I do this?

Comment: @CodeHunter it didn't work before I'm kinda sure. Anyway look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389403/asp-net-gridview-rowindex-as-commandargument).

Comment: before works because the ButtonField sets automatically the commandArgument with the index and the Button not... 
I updated to `<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Status" CommandName="atender" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />` and works great. Thanks a lot!